# How do I insert (not overwrite) a byte in hexl-mode?

Tags: emacs, hex

All of the `hexl-insert-` commands overwrite the byte at point.  It makes no difference whether `overwrite-mode` is on.

I need to actually insert a new byte at point, moving everything else down.

How can I do this in emacs?

Comment: hexl-mode has no support for inserting/deleting characters, only for overwriting existing characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might prefer `nhexl-mode`, which lets you edit the file as if it was not hexlified (basically, the hexlification in nhexl-mode is done on-the-fly during redisplay), so you can insert/remove text without any difficulty.

Comment: Thanks, I picked up `nhexl-mode` from ELPA and it worked immediately!  Their documentation is correct, though, that it is rather sensitive to file size.

Comment: @harpo: if you have performance problems with it, you might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't insert characters directly in nhexl-mode either. I have to follow such approach:

1. Open file. `M-x nhexl-mode` then `M-x nhexl-nibble-edit-mode`
2. Type **only one** character in another editor, copy it
3. Move the cursor in Emacs, `C-y` to yank this character and adjust file format
4. Move the cursor to fix hex

For example, If I want to insert `5300` to represent `S`, I need to press `C-y` to get `5353`, then edit it into `5300`

I'm using *GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)* on Windows 10 and *nhexl 1.2*